# Javascript compatibilty on different browsers issue

Tags: javascript

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(localStorage.openpages){
        alert('You have opened this already in a tab!');
        var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
        window.location.href = baseUrl + '/path/to/your/url';
    }else{
        localStorage.openpages = '1';
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            localStorage.openpages = '';
        };
    }
</script>
```

If you open the same tab (same url) , you will get the alert message and you will be redirect to the desired url .

This works perfectly in **Firefox** latest version. I can refresh my first tab and I am not redirected, also.

On **chrome** I got the alert message when I access my url (first tab) but I am not redirected. I open another tab with the same url and I got the alert message and I am redirected. Or if I refresh my first tab I am redirected. Weird !

On **IE 11** no alert , nothing, my script is ignored

On **Safari** I am afraid to try it :)

Is there a way to make that script work on every browsers (latest versions) ?

Thank you

**[`UPDATE`]**

```
if(localStorage.getItem("openpages")){
    alert('You have opened this already in a tab!');
    var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
    window.location.href = baseUrl + '/index.php/ffmpanel/customer/';
}else{
    localStorage.setItem('openpages', '1');
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        localStorage.setItem('openpages', '');
    };
}
```

With `setItem` and `getItem` , I am getting the same behaviour as described !

Comment: _On Safari I am afraid to try it :)_ You, sir, are great! Ha ha. That line made my day. Plus, to guide you, I believe you need to check if the `LocalStorage` is supported. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar  With firebug I can see the LocalStorage value on `firefox`, or `chrome` and even `ie` , so I am guessing , yes, they support :) , but I believe this part `onbeforeunload` is the issue

Comment: 1. Try using this [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) `localStorage.setItem("openpages",openpages); var openpages = localStorage.getItem("openpages") =="1");` 2. may not work from harddisk

Comment: @Chester Are you running from local or localhost?

Comment: @mplungjan `localStorage.openpages = '1';` is right...

Comment: @PraveenKumar _Note: It's recommended to use the Web Storage API (setItem, getItem, removeItem, key, length) to prevent the [pitfalls](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/objects-as-maps.html) associated with using plain objects as key-value stores._

Comment: @mplungjan Please see my update for the post , thnx

Comment: @mplungjan Agreed, but just telling... `:)`

Comment: Could you please tell my what  I described wrong in my post ? so I can update it , thank you

Comment: @Chester try `if (localStorage.getItem("openpages") =="1") ...` Also here is how to detect it is available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: PS: @Chester - nothing in IE console?

Comment: @mplungjan I don;t have any issues on firefox, if you could send me a post how can I fix it on chrome or ie , I would really appreciate it

Comment: I do not see any issues orther than `localStorage.getItem("openpages")=="1"`. Hence I ask if Internet Explorer has messages in the console (Press F12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a try with this

Test taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

and I test

```
if (localStorage.getItem("openpages") =="1")
```

instead of

```
if (localStorage.getItem("openpages"))
```

since it may be truthy

Also note that [location.origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Browser_compatibility) is not available in IE10 and lower and may be weird from file:// protocol

```js
window.onload = function() {
  if (!storageAvailable("localStorage")) {
    alert("Sorry, localStorage is not available");
    return; 
  }


  if (localStorage.getItem("openpages") == "1") { // stored as string
    alert('You have opened this already in a tab!');
    var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
    window.location.href = baseUrl + '/index.php/ffmpanel/customer/';
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('openpages', '1');
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      localStorage.setItem('openpages', '');
    };
  }

}

function storageAvailable(type) {
  try {
    var storage = window[type],
      x = '__storage_test__';
    storage.setItem(x, x);
    storage.removeItem(x);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return e instanceof DOMException && (
        // everything except Firefox
        e.code === 22 ||
        // Firefox
        e.code === 1014 ||
        // test name field too, because code might not be present
        // everything except Firefox
        e.name === 'QuotaExceededError' ||
        // Firefox
        e.name === 'NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED') &&
      // acknowledge QuotaExceededError only if there's something already stored
      storage.length !== 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thnx a lot !